# How to constrain height of AlertDialog

Tags: flutter

I show dialog with list inside it.

```
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(select_conference),
            content: ListView.separated(
              itemCount: selected.length,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => CommonDivider(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(...),
            ),
          );
        });
```

But no matter how many elements is has - dialog fills all available height. Is there any solution to solve this without calculating height of list elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap it inside a `SizedBox` or `ConstrainedBox`

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100.0),
  child: AlertDialog(
    ...
  ),
);
```

Alternatively, you can set `shrinkWrap` to `true` in your `ListView` so that it takes the least amount of vertical space necessary.

```
ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  ...
)
```

Comment: It's strange. I've already tried shrinkWrap and it didn't work. But now it works

Comment: I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container( height: 150, width: 150, ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Comment: `ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100.0),
  child: ` not worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 45):

Wrap your content with a `Column` and set `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min`:

```dart
AlertDialog(
  content: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      //your content
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You need no calculating of height, like the opener wish.

Comment: Well, that's rather kinda hack. I believe there's more elegant solution.

Comment: I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container( height: 150, width: 150, ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Comment: @Kamlesh you better to post a new question

Comment: This solution not worked for me. `AlertDialog(
  content: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      //your content
    ],
  ),`
 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A `Dialog`'s [insetPadding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog/insetPadding.html) property controls the padding around the dialog so you could set values to effectively reduce the height / width of the dialog, e.g.

```html
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 50.0,
              vertical: 100.0,
            ),
            title: Text('...'),
            content: Text('...'),
          );
        });
```

Comment: ad per 2024 not affected, the good is warp the content with column

Answer (score 0):

wrap content with column and add widget like container set that width

```
showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text("Bookmark"),
                        insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        content: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              width: screen.width * 0.70,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
```