# Flutter: How to change the width of an AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I wonder how to change the default width of an AlertDialog, I only succeeded to change the border radius :

Here is my code :

```
showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (_) =>
            new AlertDialog(
               shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
               ),
               content: ProductPreviewScreen(),
            )
    );
```

Result expected :

[image]
Any idea?

Answer (score 147):

As of May 2020, if you want to change the inset padding of a dialog, all you have to do is use the Dialog class and override the 'insetPadding' property.  You can make a dialog extend all the way to the screen edges if you want to.

You can also make some cool custom dialogs by making the dialog surface itself transparent and then add whatever widgets you want.  For example:

```
showDialog(Dialog(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Stack(
    overflow: Overflow.visible,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          color: Colors.lightBlue
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 50, 20, 20),
        child: Text("You can make cool stuff!",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: -100,
        child: Image.network("https://i.imgur.com/2yaf2wb.png", width: 150, height: 150)
      )
    ],
  )
));
```

Results in:

[image: Dialog example]

Comment: This is now the proper solution, others seem more like hacks IMO

Comment: I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container( height: 150, width: 150, ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Comment: This does not work for AlertDialog as requested.

Comment: @BillyParadise, `insetPadding` does indeed work for `AlertDialog` as well as `Dialog`, but `Dialog` is not implemented with a `ConstrainedBox`, where `AlertDialog` is.  This means that `AlertDialog` sizes itself based on its children.  To overcome this and make `AlertDialog` respond to `insetPadding` make the `AlertDialog`'s `content` `Center(child: SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, child: {YOUR ACTUAL ALERT CONTENT}))`.  You can also get rid of `Center` and set `SizeBox.height` the same as width.  See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61154#issuecomment-770627805

Comment: New Flutter Versions: Replace `overflow: Overflow.visible` with `clipBehavior: Clip.none`

Answer (score 101):

This is much more simple then the other answers make it out to be. Just use a builder to change the size of the dialog as it is being built(constructed, instantiated in other languages). This means you can also query the screen size and make a decision on how much space you want depending on said screen size. For example more space on a tablet then on a phone. You can make Scaffold a child of the Container if you need the App bar and other functions.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius:
      BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0))),
    content: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        // Get available height and width of the build area of this widget. Make a choice depending on the size.                              
        var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

        return Container(
          height: height - 400,
          width: width - 400,
        );
      },
    ),
  )
);
```

Examples of different sizes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Optionally add these to remove unneeded inner/outer border space.

```
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
```

Comment: padding is too large.

Comment: Shinriyo it’s an example. Don’t copy the size exactly change to meet your needs.

Comment: sorry to say but does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Kamlesh I am still using this code every day in my apps. Working here. Maybe you missed something and should recheck

Comment: @Kent I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
        ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Answer (score 73):

#### Using built-in dialog:

- **To increase the width:**

  ```dart
  AlertDialog(
    title: Text("AlertDialog"),
    insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  )
  ```
- **To decrease the width:**

  ```dart
  AlertDialog(
    title: Text("AlertDialog"),
    insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100),
  )
  ```

---

#### Using custom dialog:

[image]

Call this method:

```dart
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white, // Dialog background
          width: 120, // Dialog width
          height: 50, // Dialog height
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('I am a small Dialog'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: I want to make 200 x 200 pixels dialog box. How can I do in flutter? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh As of now you can't do that using `AlertDialog`, you'll have to create your own Widget. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57133640/6618622) to get started.

Comment: I love short answers!

Comment: @Kamlesh I have not tried yet but I think for your case, you may want to use dailog inside a `Container` or `SizedBox` of the size you choose.

Comment: Setting the insetPadding alone does not work. You also have to wrapt the content in a SizedBox. See my answer above.

Answer (score 24):

You could try to wrap your AlertDialog widget with ConstrainedBox widget as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52717310) and set your desired value for maxWidth parameter.

**UPDATED**

I just looked at the code of the parent of the AlertDialog widget which is the Dialog widget and found out that it wrapped its child with a ConstrainedBox widget with a minWidth of 280 pixels. This is the reason why we can't change the width of the AlertDialog widget.

Fortunately, there are two things that we can do. First option would be to alter the default minWidth of the Dialog Widget inside the dialog.dart file. Note that changing this would affect all of your flutter projects that uses the Dialog widget.

```
//inside dialog.dart

class Dialog extends StatelessWidget {

...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final DialogTheme dialogTheme = DialogTheme.of(context);
  return AnimatedPadding(
    padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets + const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 24.0),
    duration: insetAnimationDuration,
    curve: insetAnimationCurve,
    child: MediaQuery.removeViewInsets(
      removeLeft: true,
      removeTop: true,
      removeRight: true,
      removeBottom: true,
      context: context,
      child: Center(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 280.0), // You can set your desired value for minWidth here
          child: Material(
            elevation: 24.0,

            ...
```

You can then use the AlertDialog like this:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
      ),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    content: ProductPreviewScreen(),
    )
  )
);
```

The other way would be to create our own customize dialog.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => Center( // Aligns the container to center
    child: Container( // A simplified version of dialog. 
      width: 100.0,
      height: 56.0,
      color: Colors.pink,
      )
    )
 );
```

Comment: I tried wrapping the ConstrainedBox with a Center widget or Align widget. It did change the width but something is off. I also set the contentPadding parameter of the AlertDialog to zero and it eliminated the default padding of content in AlertDialog.

Comment: @JeromeEscalante I tried to wrap it in a center widget, with a minWidth, but it still doesn't work.. did the width has changed when you tried?

Comment: I dont think this is possible with the material alert dialog. You can write your own dialog to achive this. I think the material alert dialog is already insida fixed sized widget.

Comment: @Julien, I think Janpan is right. It's either we create our own customized dialog and display it using showDialog function or we could alter some parameter of the Dialog widget inside the dialog.dart file.

Answer (score 9):

Use Padding widget

```
 Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
   child://AlertDialog or any other Dialog you can use
         Dialog(
                elevation: 0.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                child: Container(
                  width: 10.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                )
            ))
```

Comment: add padding top layer... `Padding(padding: "..",child:`

Answer (score 9):

Medling with insetWidth and future builder etc. didn't work for me - just editing the content prop's width worked perfectly.

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1000), () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
      });
      return AlertDialog(
        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        title: Text(
          "Time to go pro!",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        content: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: BuySheet(
              applePayEnabled: applePayEnabled,
              googlePayEnabled: googlePayEnabled,
              applePayMerchantId: applePayMerchantId,
              squareLocationId: squareLocationId),
        ),
      );
    });
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Great! `insetPadding + container's width` makes full-width dialog.

Answer (score 8):

use Dialog()

```
Dialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
  insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: It's better to provide little detail on the answer for future reference on the SO community.

Answer (score 8):

The solution that worked for me.

Set the insetPadding of the AlertDialog.

Plus, wrap the content in a SizedBox and set the width to **MediaQuery.of(context).size.width**.

```
return AlertDialog(
  content: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: const Text("Content"),
  ),
  insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
);
```

Setting just the insetPadding alone does not work.

Comment: This perhaps works when you want the `AlertDialog` to be smaller than it's default width, but it does not make it larger than its default size, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: No. This also works if you want to make the AlertDialog bigger. I am using this code and it works.

Answer (score 7):

My solution is to enclose the Dialog in a widget that defeats the extra padding added by the Dialog class by modifying the MediaQueryData.

```
import 'package:myapp/widgets/dialog_inset_defeat.dart';
...

showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => DialogInsetDefeat(
      context: context,
      child: SimpleDialog(...),
    )
);
```

... or use showDialogWithInsets() for custom values:

```
showDialogWithInsets(
    context: context,
    edgeInsets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
    builder: (_) => SimpleDialog(...),
    )
);
```

**File dialog_inset_defeat.dart**

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// A widget to defeat the hard coded insets of the [Dialog] class which
/// are [EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 24.0)].
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Dialog], for dialogs that have a message and some buttons.
///  * [showDialog], which actually displays the dialog and returns its result.
///  * <https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html>
///  * <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913192/flutter-change-the-width-of-an-alertdialog>
class DialogInsetDefeat extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  final Widget child;
  final deInset = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: -40, vertical: -24);
  final EdgeInsets edgeInsets;

  DialogInsetDefeat({@required this.context, @required this.child, this.edgeInsets});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var netEdgeInsets = deInset + (edgeInsets ?? EdgeInsets.zero);
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(viewInsets: netEdgeInsets),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

/// Displays a Material dialog using the above DialogInsetDefeat class.
/// Meant to be a drop-in replacement for showDialog().
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Dialog], on which [SimpleDialog] and [AlertDialog] are based.
///  * [showDialog], which allows for customization of the dialog popup.
///  * <https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html>
Future<T> showDialogWithInsets<T>({
  @required BuildContext context,
  bool barrierDismissible = true,
  @required WidgetBuilder builder,
  EdgeInsets edgeInsets,
}) {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => DialogInsetDefeat(
      context: context,
      edgeInsets: edgeInsets,
      child: Builder(builder: builder),
    ),
    // Edited! barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible = true,
    barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
  );
}
```

Works for me as of Flutter 1.8.3. YMMV

Comment: Note that this is really a kludge to get around the hard-coded values in the toolkit. Later versions of Flutter may allow for more flexibility. It does try to work with the existing framework as opposed to replacing it, although each solution has its place.

Comment: @Crec Beback It can't close by tapping out of the container

Comment: @shinriyo I have not tested in a while. Reviewing my code (by sight only) I would expect the opposite error where always "barrierDismissible". I have updated above.

Comment: Gyuri Majercsik has suggested that my solution does not handle keyboard insets and that that can be fixed easily by including the current context insets by adding MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets to the netEdeInsets. I'm not in a position to test but assume he would not have added this if it was not true.

Comment: I want to make 200 x 200 pixels fixed size dialog box. How can I do in flutter? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I finally found a way to change the width of an AlertDialog.
Just wrap the "content" with a Container, and set the width to it.

```
return AlertDialog(
...
content: Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.45,
   child: ...
```

[AlertDialog with width modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGATK.png)

Comment: All the other solutions where more complicated or used another Widget.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the AlertDialog property insetPadding it will be a simple way for you.

```
 void alertBox() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
        // (horizontal:10 = left:10, right:10)(vertical:10 = top:10, bottom:10)
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        content: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
          // width = device width minus insetPadding = deviceWidth - 20  (left:10, right:10 = 20)
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 20,
          // height = device height minus insetPadding = deviceHeight - 20  (top:10, bottom:10 = 20)
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Refer this code. you can change width and height of dialogue box by setting `insetPadding`, because it taking default padding so we need to change like this.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) =>
   Dialog(
     insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 2.0),
     backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7 ,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[900],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                    child: Icon(Icons.close,color: Colors.grey,)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text("select your avatar",style: TextStyle(color: white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment:  @ Akshatha P Halady

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can actually use insetPadding and use a column inside content that will contain a SizedBox(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width).The only difference is that I used AlertDialog. Bellow is the way it worked for me. You can set dialog width by changing padding inside insetPadding. Hope i helped :).

```
dialog(){
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

return showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: true,
  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
    insetPadding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08),
    content: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 16,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          Text(
            'Hello',
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Text(
            'Description',
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: controller,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    actions: [
      FlatButton(
        child: Text("Close"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

This is how it looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvKpP.png

Comment: Pretty nice way of thinking, I have a question though. Why do you initiate the TextEditingController inside the method's block and how will you get the value outside of it.

Answer (score 3):

:

```
 return Dialog(

  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: Container(
   
    width: double.infinity,
```

use insetpadding where you are returning Dialog  and give it a double value, For my case, i gave it a 10.0
**insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),** you can give it a custom height

Answer (score 3):

you can easily Wrap you content inside your AlertDialog with Sizedbox widget contain the size you need

```
 return AlertDialog(
            content: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
```

...etc

Answer (score 2):

Add InsetPadding property like this

```
     insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero




  AlertDialog(
      title: Center(child: Text("$title")),
------------------------->Here we added the property
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0, bottom: 4),
      content: Container(
        height: 50,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: find_controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: context.watch<MediaProvider>().isChangeDialog
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      clearController(find_controller);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear))
                : null,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent)),
            hintText: 'Id',
          ),
          onChanged: (val) {
            if (val.isNotEmpty)
              context.read<MediaProvider>().isChangeDialog = true;
            else
              context.read<MediaProvider>().isChangeDialog = false;
          },
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: OutlinedButton(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.clear),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Cancel")
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<MediaProvider>().isChangeDialog = false;
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: context.watch<MediaProvider>().isChangeDialog
                      ? () {
                          context.read<MediaProvider>().isChangeDialog = false;
                          okCallback;
                        }
                      : null,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.check),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("OK")
                    ],
                  )),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After** 
[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzYK6.png]

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog(
   insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12), // Outside Padding
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12), // Content Padding
   ....
```

You can try 0/any-number instead of 12.

Answer (score 1):

```
return Dialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: X,
      ),
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the simplest way... just add  `insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,` and it will expand to max size width:

```
 showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Center(child: Text("Send Message", style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[700],
              insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              content:
```

Comment: Please show a screenshot of this working, cause currently this doesn't expand the width of the AlertDialog

Comment: You need to set the parent widget's size to `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can play with the dialog title, in most cases the dialog will expand horizontally to accommodate the title. So you can create big title to make sure the dialog will take max width. Obviously you can't just put long title, but you can build your title of two text widgets, where one of them has text color matching background. For the case where no title should be shown:

```
showDialog(
   context: context,
   builder: (_) =>
        new AlertDialog(
           title: Text('hidden title, just set font text to the same as background.',
                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
           ),
           content: ProductPreviewScreen(),
        )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

/// this works for me paste your body and see result

Future _showDialog() async {
return showDialog(
context: context,

```
barrierDismissible: true,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            /// paste your item body 
            child:body,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
},
```

);
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_smart_dialog

the package can make custom size dialog more easily and more feature in it.

for example:

```
SmartDialog.show(builder: (context) {
  return Container(
    height: 80,
    width: 180,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.black,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child:
    Text('easy custom dialog', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> To be flexible in the width and height of dialog from content use this if you want a height of dialog also set from you, you can add height in container MediaQuery.of(context).size.height then add vertical padding in insetPadding

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      children:[
        Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: widget
        )
      ]
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :D

I am no expert, but I don't know why are they making it so complicated. I just wanted to increase the width a little which is what the OP and many would want.

A `SizedBox` does the trick.

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => const AlertDialog(
      actions: [
        Text("Some text"),

        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
          width: 200, // width here
        ),

        Text("Some more text"),
      ]),
)
```

Thanks!
Upvote if it helps :)

Comment: You can also set the width to a certain % of the screen width using MediaQuery

Answer (score 0):

just wrap content with column

```
showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text("Bookmark"),
                        insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        content: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              width: screen.width * 0.70,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using listview inside the dialog box so I was not using
shrink wrap inside ListView hopes this will help someone.

```
ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap : true...
...
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package and it is wonderful. use its dialog, easily sizable

```
Get.generalDialog(pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Constants.padding), ),
        elevation: 0, backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        children: [Center(child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(width: Get.width * 0.95,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: Constants.padding,top: Constants.avatarRadius
                  + Constants.padding, right: Constants.padding,bottom: Constants.padding
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: Constants.avatarRadius),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                color: Get.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Constants.padding),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(color: Colors.black,offset: Offset(0,10), blurRadius: 10 ),
                ]
              ),
              child: Text('body'),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: Constants.padding, right: Constants.padding,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent, radius: Constants.avatarRadius,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(Constants.avatarRadius)),
                  child: Icon(Icons.done, size: 24, color: Colors.white,)
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              //right: Constants.padding,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent, radius: Constants.avatarRadius,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(Constants.avatarRadius)),
                  child: InkWell(child: const Icon(Icons.close, size: 24, color: Colors.white,), onTap: (){Get.back();},)
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ))],
      );
    }, barrierDismissible: true, barrierLabel: '');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to increase width of the alert

**Example**:

```
return AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Select Birth Date"),
      content: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 300,
        child: CupertinoDatePicker(
          mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
          initialDateTime: DateTime(1969, 1, 1),
          onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
            // Do something
           
          },
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Select"),
          onPressed: () {
            widget.onSelected(selectedDate);
            Navigator.pop(context);
            //.....
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

in the alert box ..just add inset padding as

alertbox(

..
insetpadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10),

..

),

It will change the width