# How to set width of Alert dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

I want to add width to my alert box in flutter. How can I achieve that? What ever I am trying to increase the width its not getting reflecting. why? inside of Alert dialog class they have added the min width as 280 so in this case what I have to do?

I am very new to flutter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: change the width of an AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913192/flutter-change-the-width-of-an-alertdialog)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way, create a custom dialog class by copying the original dialog.dart content (or you can get it from flutter repository) and modifying the aforementioned parameters and using it when you need customization.

Comment: for sure it will work just change this line             constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 280.0),