# Flutter DateTimePicker size is too small | Resize Flutter DateTimePicker size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, android-datepicker, dart-null-safety

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to maximize the DatePicker size due to user feedback (too small on other devices). I've tried adding a builder but it didn't make any difference.

The following is my current code:

```
_datePicker() {
return showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year),
  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
  initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Container(
      height: 555,
      width: 500,
      child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

}

I'd like to refrain using a library and stick to the stock widgets as much as possible.

Let me know if I missed anything. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showDatePicker "Shows a dialog containing a Material Design date picker." as per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html).

My initial solution came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913192/flutter-change-the-width-of-an-alertdialog) but it doesn't seem to work.

Due to time constraints, I'll use [SfDateRangePicker](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/latest/datepicker/SfDateRangePicker-class.html) for now which solves the width issue I have and will try to find another way in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can resize date picker dialog by Container(), SizedBox() etc. using it in builder,incrase height and width of sizebox

Here is working example,

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.date_range),
          onPressed: () async {
            await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year),
                lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                    width: 500.0,
                    height: 500.0,
                    child: child,
                  ));
                });


          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Here is another example

```
 await showDatePicker(
               context: context,
               initialDate: DateTime.now(),
               firstDate: DateTime.now(),
               lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 356)),
               builder: (context, child) {
                 return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                     children: <Widget>[
                       Padding(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                         child: Container(
                           height: 700,
                           width: 700,
                           child: child,
                         ),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 );
               },
             );
```